# Error? Reading variable inside IBAction Button

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, ibaction

I have an IBAction that needs to read from a variable. However, when placing the variable outside of the `viewDidLoad` I receive the error

> Cannot use instance member 'animal' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available

My code is as follows. When I move the variable back inside the `viewDidLoad` the error states that animalName is undeclared

```
var animalName = (String(format: "%03d", animal.speciesId!))

@IBAction func megaKeyIBO(_ sender: Any) {
    animalName = (String(format: "%03d", animal.speciesId!)) + "-merg"
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    //variable was originally here before moving to top
    var animalName = (String(format: "%03d", animal.speciesId!))
}
```

Comment: We need to see the definition of `animal`, but it sounds like it's an instance member that may not have been initialized when the property initializer runs.

Comment: Do you need the `animalName` to be populated at initialization? Why not make it optional and initialize it in `viewDidLoad`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because you're trying to initialize your animalName before your property animal.speciesId! has been initialized. A simply way to solve would be this:

```
var animalName: String!

@IBAction func megaKeyIBO(_ sender: Any) {
    animalName = (String(format: "%03d", animal.speciesId!)) + "-merg"
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Initialize on viewDidLoad
    animalName = (String(format: "%03d", animal.speciesId!))
}
```

Comment: Ugh, it's always the simplest one-liners that take me the longest to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the variable `animalName` as a local variable when you declare it in `viewDidLoad()`

Local variables only work in the functions they are declared in order to use `animalName` in the button you created it must be declared as an instance variable or in the function for the button